# When I use the int keyword the output is always 0

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;                

class ran{
  private:
    int population;
  public:
    void set(int x){
      int population = x;
    }
    int get(){
      return population;
    }    
};
int main() {
  ran linux;
  linux.set(50900);
  cout <<linux.get();
  return 0;
}
```

In line no 7 when I set population to be x with the int keyword and run the the code the output will always be 0 but when I remove the int keyword it works fine can someone tell why this is happening.[From where I got the basis of the code](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_encapsulation.asp).

Comment: When you put `int` you have a local variable, get a textbook.

Comment: `int population = x;` doesn't have any effect than assigning a local variable. Did you  mean to write `population = x;` instead?

Comment: `int population` creates a new variable. So now you have two of them!

Comment: Enable your compiler warnings.  Your compiler could have told you about this mistake.

Comment: As an aside, you can *never, ever* learn C++ by writing random code and see what happens. Instead try to first learn how it is supposed to work, perhaps starting here https://www.learncpp.com/

Comment: [Turn your compiler's warning on](https://godbolt.org/z/MMardqxzY).

Comment: Seems we get this a lot, is there a decent dup?

Comment: What @DrewDormann said is important.  You can even do this: https://godbolt.org/z/b76s7E459

Answer (score 4):

When you write `int population = x;` it creates a new local variable inside that function called `population` and sets its value to `x`. The class variable `population` is a separate variable which is not affected.

When you write `population = x;` it looks for a variable called `population`, finds one in the class, and sets the class variable `population` to `x`.

Comment: Remember, to use pass by reference, you must also set it to `int&`, I think.

Comment: @cs1349459 What are you talking about? Who's talking about passing by reference? And why would that ever be relevant here when passing a plain `int` to a function? There's not even any mention of "out parameters" which *might* make your comment make a little bit of sense.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I'm sorry, I don't know why I said that.